# Android mouse cursor event /dev/uinput not moving on Y axis

Tags: android, c, events, java-native-interface, mouse

I'm trying to move cursor mouse on Android using /dev/uinput and ioctl.

Here is my code :

```
int fd = -1;
struct input_event ev;

int uinput_open_device() {
fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd < 0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Code C", "Failed to Open Event");
    return -1;
}
return fd;
}

int dev_uinput_init_mouse(char *name) {
struct uinput_user_dev dev;

fd = uinput_open_device();
if (fd > 0) {
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, BTN_LEFT);

    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REL);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_X);
    ioctl(fd, UI_SET_RELBIT, REL_Y);

    memset(&dev, 0, sizeof(dev));
    strncpy(dev.name, name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE);

    dev.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
    dev.id.vendor  = 0x1;
    dev.id.product = 0x1;
    dev.id.version = 1;

    if (write(fd, &dev, sizeof(dev)) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Code C", "Failed to write");
        close(fd);
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "IOCTL", "Create Failed...");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
}
return fd;

void dev_uinput_sync(int fd) {
memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(struct input_event));

ev.type = EV_SYN;
ev.code = SYN_REPORT;
ev.value = 0;
if (write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event)) < 0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Code C", "Failed to write");
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Code C", "Sync OK !");
}
}

void ptr_abs(int fd, int x, int y) {
memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(struct input_event));
ev.type = EV_REL;
ev.code = REL_X;
ev.value = x;
write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event))

memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(struct input_event));
ev.type = EV_REL;
ev.code = REL_Y;
ev.value = y;
write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event);
dev_uinput_sync(fd);
}

void dev_uinput_close(int fd) {
ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
close(fd);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_mouseSimulation(JNIEnv *env,    jobject instance, jint absX, jint absY) {
ptr_abs(fd, absX, absY);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_openFD(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
dev_uinput_init_mouse("uinput-sample-test");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_closeFD(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
dev_uinput_close(fd);
}
```

All these functions are called through a Service in my Android application. 
The function `Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_mouseSimulation(int Xaxis, int Yaxis)` is called with value for Xaxis and Yaxis but on the screen we can see the mouse moving only on X axis and not on Y axis.

For example, if I call `Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_mouseSimulation(200, 100)` the cursor will move 200 pixels on X axis and nothing on Y axis.

As you can see the movement is executed by the function `void ptr_abs(int fd, int x, int y)`

The `write` on the function does not fail. I enabled the movement on Y axis  using `ioctl` on `REL_Y` function.

I'm compiling this code on Android API 19.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Because it's a C code ?

Comment: Is your code compiling? It looks like you missed a bracket here: write(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event); (it's writing the REL_Y event)

Comment: Yes it's compiling. I even compiled it on Unix Environnement and works perfectly in X & Y axis !
Only in Android Environnement where I face this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved... I removed every __android_log_print and condition in every write function and it works...

Strange...